# Why is it the case that "in the technical sciences" propositional logic it is accepted that If P = FALSE then Q = TRUE = TRUE?

Tags: if-statement, logic

P = False
Q = True

Every calculator I use states: If P then Q = True. This is commented on in the sources I can find: [http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ramsey/Logic/IfThen.html](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Eramsey/Logic/IfThen.html)

Most of the question is in the title. I'm wondering not why this is the case, exactly, but why it is accepted that this is the case. What is the underlying decision that resulted in this being considered the norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to this question, I found that I was essentially guilty of projecting meaning onto a system that made no claims to be modelling reality. Remember, this is a arbitrary model in classical logic. If it is defined that this is how this logic works, that is how it works. It needs no further justification than that.

The further discussion is 'does this model reality well?'. This is apparently a recognized field of debate. To further explore the debate around the use of this form of classical logic, I would point you towards Wittgenstein's "Meaning is Use" sections in his "Philosophical Investigations" book and the arguments presented in "Wittgenstein on Meaning".

Answer (score 2):

First, the logical statement is true in classical propositional logic. But, there are many logics that treat the logical connectives different. Please note that in "technical sciences", such as Computer Science,  many non-classical logics are applied. Famous examples are Prolog, Stable Model Semantics, Answer Set Programming. In such logics, statements of the form "if p, then q" are completed in the sense to translate the "if then" into an "if and only if". This means that "if p then q" is true if and only if both are false or both are true.

Consequently, we use logics with different properties in different contexts. Classical logic is often appropriate when talking about mathematical statements; please note that interactive theorem provers, such as Coq, that are used to prove theorems, do not rely on classical logics. Classical as well as other logics are also studies in "non-technical fields" such as Philosophy and Psychology.

To make your answer short: Classical logic goes back to Aristotle, and is a reasonable understanding of "if then". If it would not exist, we would invent a new logical connective or would use just negation and disjunction. However, this definition of implication is crtisized as it does not meet the expecation of non-logically trained humans (see [my paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221251249_An_Abductive_Model_for_Human_Reasoning))

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! To expand slightly on my original question: It seems to me that the statement under discussion here is logically valid but not meaningful, under the principle of non-contradiction. Positions TT and TF are both TRUE. It seems to me that these are therefore not in the same statement, but in two separate statements: the statement in the world where the statement exists and the world where it does not. My question is, I guess, is this recognised in any systems or is this faulty association?

Comment: I am not completely sure about your question; maybe you refer to [intuitionistic logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic)?

Comment: That is indeed an example of a field attempting to handle the problem I am referring to, thanks for the reference! I am basically querying that there seems to be no consideration for the fact that there are three potential outcomes for P -> Q, TRUE, FALSE and "this option means the question was never asked", i.e. the statement is non-meaningful by the principle that a statement that refutes it's own existence is meaningless.

Comment: From my perspective, you refer to [three-valued logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) or [proof-theoretical semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_of_logic). It would be important how your third truth value behaves or how the inference system that decides that the implication is irrelevant to evaluate whether such a logic have been considered in the past.